# Month pickers for .NET WinForms

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i show month selection calendar in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270089/how-can-i-show-month-selection-calendar-in-my-app)

I have to select only month from a date picker Control. I know there is Date Format Property available for the same purpose and i am pretty happy with that.

The only problem is that when I open my date picker popup, the date picker calendar popup is in Month - Mode. Is it possible to be same on Year Mode.

And Also, I don't want to display the inner date on calendar control which is placed just below on calender control.

Any suggestions?

Vijay

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own control simply

For selecting month you can easily use ComboBox and for year a NumericUpDown control
or add both of them to a user control and return selected month and year