# How to customize a DatePicker/MonthCalendar?

Tags: c#, winforms, datepicker, monthcalendar

Question: How can I make the following changes to a DatePicker/MonthCalendar when the calendar is opened:

1. Highlight weekends and holidays in red
2. Make holidays, weekends, and past dates unselectable
3. Mark past dates with gray color

I tried to use the OnPaint event, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36152013/how-to-customize-calendar-in-datetimepicker-control/36211949#36211949