# How can I set the DateTimePicker dropdown to select Years or Months only?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetimepicker, monthcalendar

Like discussed in [How can I set the datetimepicker dropdown to show Months only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846455/how-can-i-set-the-datetimepicker-dropdown-to-show-months-only) there was a possibility to overwrite `DateTimePicker` to get a `MonthPicker`.

I have read a lot of sites but didn't figure out how to do similar to get a `YearPicker`.
Maybe someone can help out.

Comment: Not an option.  Consider a NumericUpDown or ComboBox to pick years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This Custom Control tweaks a little the standard DateTimePicker to get a Year or Month selection style only.

▶ The standard DateTimePicker's **`CustomFormat`** and **`Format`** properties are *disabled*, setting internally the former to `yyyy` or `MMMM` (a simple modification can add different formats) and the latter to `DateTimePickerFormat.Custom`. These properties are hidden from the PropertyGrid an cannot be changed.

▶ The browsing functionality is maintained, but limited to the Decade/Year or Decade/Year/Month selection.
Clicking the DTP's Title Area, brings on the Decade selector and the previous and next Buttons are of course functional (these can only show years).

▶ The DTP is closed and the current value set when a [`MCN_VIEWCHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/mcn-viewchange) notification reveals, passing the current selection level in a [`NMVIEWCHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-nmviewchange) structure, that the current selection has reached the View Mode set by the **`SelectionMode`** property.
This property value is an enumerator which, in turn, reflects the MonthCalendar's [`MCM_SETCURRENTVIEW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/mcm-setcurrentview) message values.

▶ The current View is set sending a `MCM_SETCURRENTVIEW` message to the MonthCalendar control, changing the default View to **`MCMV_DECADE`** or **`MCMV_YEAR`** (depending on the current `SelectionMode`) each time the MonthCalendar control is shown. The opening animation is then preserved.

▶ The only style changed is [`MCS_NOTODAY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/month-calendar-control-styles), set in the `OnHandleCreated` method. It can be switched on/off at any time, calling the `ShowMonCalToday()` method.
This style shows the `Today` date, at the bottom of the DateTimerPicker. It sets the current Year or Month value when clicked.

---

This is how it works:

[image: DateTimePicker Years Month Only]

Tested on VisualStudio 2017.
.Net Framework 4.8 (only).

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[DesignerCategory("Code")]
public class MonthYearPicker : DateTimePicker
{
    private string m_CustomFormat = "yyyy";
    private DateTimePickerFormat m_Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
    private SelectionViewMode m_SelectionMode = SelectionViewMode.Year;
    private bool m_ShowToday = false;
    private IntPtr hWndCal = IntPtr.Zero;

    public MonthYearPicker() {
        base.CustomFormat = m_CustomFormat;
        base.Format = m_Format;
    }

    [DefaultValue(SelectionViewMode.Year)]
    [Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    [Category("Appearance"), Description("Set the current selection mode to either Month or Year")]
    public SelectionViewMode SelectionMode {
        get => m_SelectionMode;
        set {
            if (value != m_SelectionMode) {
                m_SelectionMode = value;
                m_CustomFormat = m_SelectionMode == SelectionViewMode.Year ? "yyyy" : "MMMM";
                base.CustomFormat = m_CustomFormat;
            }
        }
    }

    [DefaultValue(false)]
    [Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    [Category("Appearance"), Description("Shows or hides \"Today\" date at the bottom of the Calendar Control")]
    public bool ShowToday {
        get => m_ShowToday;
        set {
            if (value != m_ShowToday) {
                m_ShowToday = value;
                ShowMonCalToday(m_ShowToday);
            }
        }
    }

    [DefaultValue("yyyy")]
    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public new string CustomFormat {
        get => base.CustomFormat;
        set => base.CustomFormat = m_CustomFormat;
    }

    [DefaultValue(DateTimePickerFormat.Custom)]
    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public new DateTimePickerFormat Format {
        get => base.Format;
        set => base.Format = m_Format;
    }

    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        ShowMonCalToday(m_ShowToday);
    }

    protected override void OnDropDown(EventArgs e)
    {
        hWndCal = SendMessage(this.Handle, DTM_GETMONTHCAL, 0, 0);
        if (hWndCal != IntPtr.Zero) {
            SendMessage(hWndCal, MCM_SETCURRENTVIEW, 0, (int)(MonCalStyles)m_SelectionMode);
        }
        base.OnDropDown(e);
    }

    private void ShowMonCalToday(bool show)
    {
        int styles = SendMessage(this.Handle, DTM_GETMCSTYLE, 0, 0).ToInt32();
        styles = show ? styles &~(int)MonCalStyles.MCS_NOTODAY : styles | (int)MonCalStyles.MCS_NOTODAY;
        SendMessage(this.Handle, DTM_SETMCSTYLE, 0, styles);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg) {
            case WM_NOTIFY:
                var nmh = (NMHDR)m.GetLParam(typeof(NMHDR));
                switch (nmh.code) {
                    case MCN_VIEWCHANGE:
                        var nmView = (NMVIEWCHANGE)m.GetLParam(typeof(NMVIEWCHANGE));
                        if (nmView.dwNewView < (MonCalView)m_SelectionMode) {
                            SendMessage(this.Handle, DTM_CLOSEMONTHCAL, 0, 0);
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        // NOP: Add more notifications handlers...
                        break;
                }
                break;
            default:
                // NOP: Add more message handlers...
                break;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    public enum SelectionViewMode : int
    {
        Month = MonCalView.MCMV_YEAR,
        Year = MonCalView.MCMV_DECADE,
    }

    // Move to a NativeMethods class, eventually
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    internal const int WM_NOTIFY = 0x004E;
    internal const int MCN_VIEWCHANGE = -750;

    internal const int DTM_FIRST = 0x1000;
    internal const int DTM_GETMONTHCAL = DTM_FIRST + 8;
    internal const int DTM_SETMCSTYLE = DTM_FIRST + 11;
    internal const int DTM_GETMCSTYLE = DTM_FIRST + 12;
    internal const int DTM_CLOSEMONTHCAL = DTM_FIRST + 13;

    internal const int MCM_FIRST = 0x1000;
    internal const int MCM_GETCURRENTVIEW = MCM_FIRST + 22;
    internal const int MCM_SETCURRENTVIEW = MCM_FIRST + 32;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct NMHDR
    {
        public IntPtr hwndFrom;
        public UIntPtr idFrom;
        public int code;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct NMVIEWCHANGE
    {
        public NMHDR nmhdr;
        public MonCalView dwOldView;
        public MonCalView dwNewView;
    }

    internal enum MonCalView : int
    {
        MCMV_MONTH = 0,
        MCMV_YEAR = 1,
        MCMV_DECADE = 2,
        MCMV_CENTURY = 3
    }

    internal enum MonCalStyles : int
    {
        MCS_DAYSTATE = 0x0001,
        MCS_MULTISELECT = 0x0002,
        MCS_WEEKNUMBERS = 0x0004,
        MCS_NOTODAYCIRCLE = 0x0008,
        MCS_NOTODAY = 0x0010,
        MCS_NOTRAILINGDATES = 0x0040,
        MCS_SHORTDAYSOFWEEK = 0x0080,
        MCS_NOSELCHANGEONNAV = 0x0100
    }
}
```