# DateTimePicker Tool in VB.net showing some red mark

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I am using DateTimePicker  tool in VB.net .
When I build the project a red color mark is coming ( As Shown in screenshot ).

How to remove those red color marks ?
Any properties for that ?
That is looking odd.
Thanks
[image]

Edit1 : It is coming in both debug and release mode

Comment: Go to `Project > Properties > Application tab` and then tick the `Enable XP visual styles` checkbox.

Comment: The red mark indicates today's date and provides an easy way for the user to reset to today. That's why it says "Today" next to it. It's supposed to be there. On Windows 10, by default, it's a blue square instead of a red circle(ish).

Comment: It can be deactivated using the [Month Calendar Control Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/month-calendar-control-styles) if you set `MCS_NOTODAYCIRCLE` using the [SendMessage function (winuser.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage) as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61696967/change-week-display-in-datetimepicker-control/61697311#61697311). The example is for C# so you would need to transfer that (or research how to use sendmessage) in VB.Net

Comment: @jmcilhinney IIRC, it's the same even for Windows 7. I believe the OP just has visual styles disabled (judging by the appearance of the other controls as well).

Comment: @41686d6564, you are likely correct, although the question is whether visual styles are disabled intentionally or not. I think that it's been quite a while since VS didn't have visual styles turned on by default, so that may be an explicit decision. Even with visual styles turned on though, there will still be some sort of indicator for today's date.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Well but the indicator can be disabled as described in the link I posed above.

Comment: See the notes and the methods used here: [How can I set the DateTimePicker dropdown to select Years or Months only?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61287097/7444103). There's also a specific method, `ShowMonCalToday()`.

Comment: Thank you all Enabling XP visual styles worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the question comments, turning `Enable XP visual styles` *on* in *Project properties/Application* results in a DTP with a (much neater-looking) blue box around today's date:

[image]

To me this is somewhat anachronistic as I would have thought that having `Enable XP visual styles` *off* would result in the current OS (in my case Windows 10 Pro) determining the appearance. Windows XP just won't die, will it?

Comment: Well, I think the DateTimePicker is even older than XP. So *"Enable XP visual styles"* was the fancy new shit these days ^^ The red circle looks to be even from the pre XP era.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ It does look a little like it's painted with blood on a stick ...

Comment: I always preferred the 3D look but nobody asked me.

Comment: What look do you prefer @Mary? ;)

Comment: Thanks for asking @SteveCinq :-)

Comment: Thank you all Enabling XP visual styles worked for me